# vim-powerline: customizing the status line to display an indicator when there is a modified file in the buffers

Tags: vim, vim-powerline

I use [vim-powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline) plugin to customize the vim status line. As of now, the status line displays a `+` when the current buffer is modified. When I switch to a un modified buffer I can no longer tell if there is a modified buffer in the project. Currently, I use the `:files` or `:buffers` command to locate the modified buffers.

Is it possible to customize the status line to display an indicator when there is a modified file in the buffers(even when the buffer is not current).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a great idea, and it shouldn't be too difficult to implement. I recommend that you switch to the [new Powerline project](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline), and submit an issue in the issue tracker there. I don't follow up on issues posted elsewhere, so please use the official issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks for building a great plugin. I have added an issue at github for this enhancement request.(https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/issues/173)